# Google Map Javascript Only loads after refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api-javascript-client

Using Google Map API, I have embedded Google Map (Javascript) in my page. However, the map will only load after I refresh the page once.

I looked up on many past threads, to which many mentioned the caused related turbolinks.
I tried many of those but still it didn't work.

Application.html.erb

```html
     <%= yield %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_BROWSER_KEY']}" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag "map" %>
```

Show.html.erb

```html
<div id="map"
  style="width: 100%;
  height: 300px;"
  data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= ENV['GOOGLE_API_BROWSER_KEY'] %>&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript/packs/map.js

```html
import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement) {
  const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  map.addMarkers(markers);
  if (markers.length === 0) {
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else if (markers.length === 1) {
    map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  } else {
    map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any additional question or if you need anymore info.

Appreciate all your helps!

Comment: This is a turbolinks issue. Try to initialize the map by listening to `turbolinks:load`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to initialize turbolinks, so I lookup for error message in the console. Therefore, I found that the issue is due to including the API twice, in the application.html.erb and show.html.erb
But, thank you for your suggestion!